# STL How to save iterator after erase()

Tags: c++, stl

1. I want to process each node in a `vector<int>` container.
2. Suppose `vector<int>` contains 0, 1, 2, and 3 and an iterator is pointing to 2.
3. I want to erase 2 without losing the information of the position of iterator since I want to process "3" after erasing 2.
4. Here is what I have done, but the output does not show what I intended.
5. Here are my questions:

Q1) When `vector<int>::iterator oldIter = iter;` is executed,
Does `oldIter` create a new iterator object?

Q2) Why does the value of the iterator remain the same after incrementing it?

Q3) What is a good way to erase a node without losing
   the location of the iterator?

Q4) Finally, a trivial question. I tried `cout << iter;` but it does not work. Why is that?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){

vector<int> vContainer;
vector<int>::iterator iter;

vContainer.push_back(0);
vContainer.push_back(1);
vContainer.push_back(2);
vContainer.push_back(3);

for(int i = 0; i < vContainer.size(); i++){
  cout << vContainer[i] << endl;
}

printf("iter: %x\n", iter);
iter = vContainer.begin();


// Move the itertor to the 2.
while(*iter != 2){
    iter++;
}

printf("iter: %x\n", iter);

vector<int>::iterator oldIter = iter;
printf("\nBefore erase(oldIter)\n");
printf("oldIter: %x\n", oldIter);
printf("iter: %x\n", iter);

iter++;

printf("\nAfter incrementing iter\n");
printf("oldIter: %x\n", oldIter);
printf("iter: %x\n", iter);

vContainer.erase(oldIter);

printf("\nAfter erase(oldIter)\n");
printf("oldIter: %x\n", oldIter);
printf("iter: %x\n", iter);

for(int i = 0; i < vContainer.size(); i++){
  cout << vContainer[i] << endl;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When `vector<int>::iterator oldIter = iter;` is executed, Does oldIter
>   create a new iterator object?

Yes.

> Why does the value of the iterator remain the same after incrementing
>   it?

It doesn't. What made you conclude that it does? Your `printf` statements? Those are invalid. `printf` does not know how to handle vector iterators. Your calls to it are undefined behavior.

> What is a good way to erase a node without losing the location of the
>   iterator?

Capture the return value of the `erase` call.

```
iter = vContainer.erase(iter);
```

> Finally, a trivial question. I tried cout << iter; but it does not
>   work. Why is that?

Because there is no `operator<<` overload which takes an `std::ostream` on the left, and a vector iterator on the right. And unlike `printf`, `std::ostream::operator<<` is typesafe, so you will get a compile time error, instead of runtime undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. For the question (3), where does the return value point to? Previously, it points to "2" but now it is gone.

Comment: @PeterHwang: It will point to the element that moves into the erased position. The 3 in your case. If you erase the last element, it will return the iterator that would be returned by a call to `end()`.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, erase() remove the node which is pointed by the iterator and move all remaining nodes by one. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, do *not* remove nodes individually. Instead, use `std::remove_if()` in combination with `std::vector<...>::erase()`: This turns a potentially quadratic algorithm into a linear one. That is, you'd use something like this

```
vContainer.erase(std::remove_if(vContainer.begin(),
                                vContainer.end(),
                                [](int value){ return someCondition(value); }),
                               vContainer.end());
```

Otherwise, the easiest approach is probably to just restore the location with an offset:

```
int offset(std::distance(vContainer.begin(), it));
vContainer.erase(it);
it = vContainer.begin() + offset;
```

Since `erase(it)` will move all objects after the location `it` it is fairly expensive, though. Having an algorithm like `std::remove_if()` aggregate the changes and move each element at most once rather than potentially once per `erase()` is a lot more efficient.

Addressing your specific questions:

1. `std::vector<int>::iterator oldIter = iter` obviously creates a copy of `iter`. Note, however, that all iterators referring to the object referenced by `it` or following that objects are invalidated when using `erase(it)`.
2. When incrementing an iterator it doesn't stay in the same location. If you think it does you probably determined the iterator location incorrectly. The best approach to determine the iterator location for a random access iterator is to get the offset from the start of the sequence, e.g., using `std::distance(v.begin(), it)` (assuming `it` is an iterator in the range `v.begin()` to `v.end()`).
3. Just keep the offset from the start and restore it.
4. Iterators can't be printed. Their value doesn't make any sense. The fact that you got something printed using `printf()` doesn't mean anything because the type `%x` can only be used for integer values and using it with a different type in the specific location is undefined behavior. See above how to get a reasonable indication of the iterator location. Note that the result of `std::distance(v.begin(), it)` is some integral type: you are best off printing it with IOStreams which figure out the type automatically rather than guessing its type for the format specifier of `printf()`.